# pgadmin4, got "Unable to connect to server: SSL error: invalid padding" error

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I try to connect `cloud sql` using `ssl` mode.

But got

> Unable to connect to server:  SSL error: invalid padding

How can I solve this? thanks.